# Publishing a NPM library using Typescript and Webpack as bundler

Tags: npm, webpack

I am trying to configure webpack and typescript in such a way so that it will be possible for me to publish all the files to npm repository and then use it in a different project. I successfully upload the files, hovewer when I am installing the package in a different project and try to use the function, it says that the function is not exported giving me this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , light_trading_chart_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createChart) is not a function
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "lib",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And here is webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "index": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts')
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /webpack.config.js/],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
    static: './lib',
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'light-trading-chart',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
};
```

[image: The folder structure seems fine to me after the build]